# Integrate $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$ using trig substitution

Tags: calculus

During our integration of the following integral, using $x = 4 \sin \theta$

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} dx$$

We eventually come to the following point:

$$\int \frac{16 {\sin ^2 \theta} }{4 \sqrt{\cos ^2 \theta}} dx$$

At this point, we say that $\sqrt{\cos ^2 \theta} = \cos \theta$ and then complete the integral

But doesn't $\sqrt{\cos ^2 \theta} = |\cos \theta|$

What is going on?

Comment: You forgot couple of things there.

Comment: Right, sorry.  My question isn't about the integration, its only why do we ignore the absolute value of cosine?

Comment: That matters not in the process of finding primitives.

Comment: A question in the same thought of line: Why do you think $x^{2}/(\sqrt{16 - x^{2}})$ is meaningful in $\int$?

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx\;,$$ Let $x=4\sin \phi\;,$ Then $dx = 4\cos \phi d\phi$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{16\sin^2 \phi}{4|\cos \phi|}\cdot 4\cos \phi d\phi = \pm 8\int 2\sin^2 \phi d \phi$$

Now Using $\bullet\; 2\sin^2 \phi = 1-\cos 2\phi$ and $\bullet\; \sin 2\phi = 2\sin \phi\cdot \cos \phi.$

so we get $$\displaystyle I = \pm 8\int (1-\cos 2\phi)d\phi = \pm 8\left[\phi-\frac{\sin 2\phi}{2}\right]+\mathcal{C} = \pm 8\left[\phi-\sin \phi \cdot \cos \phi\right]+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =\pm 8\left[\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)-\frac{x\sqrt{16-x^2}}{16}\right]+\mathcal{C} $$

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to never forget dx in integration. Let us reconsider your calculations:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx$$

You take $x=4\sin\theta$. By taking the substitution, you also have to rewrite $dx$. $dx=d(4\sin\theta)=4\cos \theta d\theta$. After substituting, you get:

$$\int\frac{16 \sin^2 \theta}{4 \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta}}4\cos\theta d\theta$$
After this, it is quite easy to finish the calculation

Comment: You are right that $\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta}=|\cos \theta|$. So you have to mention the intervals.

Comment: Is it because the domain is $x \in [-4, 4]$ and $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{16 - x^2} \ge 0$ $\implies \theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$] for which cosine is always positive?

Comment: Right, but how can we just cancel out $|cos \theta|$ with $cos \theta$ ?  One has the absolute value the other doesnt

Comment: You can consider it as a definite integral. Sines and cosines are periodic functions. It's enough to look only at $[0,2\pi]$. After deeper look into it, you will be able to infer the shape of the antiderivative. By the way:
$$\int 16 \sin^2 \theta d\theta=16 \int \sin^2 \theta d\theta=16\int \frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}d \theta=....$$

Comment: I agree. This is exactly what the asker had to come up with.